# how is volumetric data better over polygonal data?

Tags: data-structures, graphics, 3d, blender, mesh

I came across this research topics while searching for data structures for storing 3D meshes. The two commonly mentioned were polygonal data and volumetric data.

which is better and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say one is better than the other, each has strengths and weaknesses. The one you use will depend on the task you are trying to perform.

The strength of polygonal data would be for surface only objects, often created by hand with modelling/sculpting software.

Volumetric data is more often used for simulations like smoke and fluid.